# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working in chrome app

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-app

I'm using bootstrap in a chrome app and trying to do basic things, like use a dropdown menu.  None of the [code samples](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) seem to be 'dropping down' after I click on the button.  It's just a styled button that seems to have no code triggered off the 'click' event.

Bootstrap version: 3.3.1

jQuery version: 2.1.3

My `third-party/css` and `third-party/js` directories seem to have the regular and minified versions of bootstrap.  I'm not sure if I can get away with only the `.min` versions.

```
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="assets/third-party/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Single button -->
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/third-party/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/third-party/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### Edit

I've isolated that things work when `index.html` is directly opened by a browser, but the sample simple dropdown example does NOT work when opened within a chrome app.

To remove any ambiguity, the example chrome project available [on GitHub](https://github.com/labs-stellios/bootstrap-dropdown-test/tree/master/app).

Comment: Forgot my crystal ball at the office. Define "not working".

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for forcing me to ask better.  Editing now...

Comment: Did you verify the scripts are actually available? Could it be they are just not loaded at all?

Comment: There could be something there.  How can I verify the scripts are actually available? And what action can I take if they are not?

Comment: Did you include the dropdowns.js?

Comment: Have you checked the console for your app window? I would start with that. Either through `chrome://inspect/#apps` or the [App Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc)

Comment: You also need to initialize if you're not using data-attributes. Like this `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`

Comment: I ran your code on bootply and it works: http://www.bootply.com/wInFUzhIbO. Must not be loading the scripts.

Comment: @Xan, No errors in the js console.

Comment: @itamar, I tried initializing two different ways with no success: `$('#dropdownMenu1').dropdown();
 $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`

Comment: Sounds like a CSP issue. Are you dead certain that in the console of your window there are no errors?

Comment: @Xan, dead certain.  Developer tools with the console tab selected is always open when I run apps I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

forgot the ID

```
<!-- CSS -->
      <link href="assets/third-party/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Single button -->
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownMenu1">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- JavaScript -->
      <script src="assets/third-party/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/third-party/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Did not work either.  The issue seems to be tied to using bootstrap within a chrome app.

Comment: try using script. create an onClick function to the button id to toggle the drop down menu on mobile devices.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```